# How to get first string before blank string with shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have string lists

```
Facades core/app/Firstmedia/Facades/FmSettingFacades.php
core/app/Firstmedia/FmSettingFacades.php
core/app/Http/Controllers/Frontpage/ContentController.php
core/app/Http/Controllers/Frontpage/HomeController.php
core/app/Http/Controllers/Frontpage/OTPController.php
core/resources/views/admin/pages/solution/form.blade.php
core/resources/views/frontpage/pages/content.blade.php
core/routes/web.php
backend core/resources/views/backend/pages/content.blade.php
```

I just want get first string before blank string

Expected output:

```
Facades
backend
```

I try this code

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='copy.md'
n=1
tanggal=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
tanggalWaktu=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
rm -rf ./update/$tanggal
mkdir -p ./update/$tanggal
mkdir -p ./logs

while read line; do
    echo "$line" | awk '{sub(/:.*/,x)}1'
done < $filename
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a row contains more than 1 column, output first column:

```
awk 'NF>1{print $1}'
```

`awk` uses spaces and tabs as default field separator.

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: A small correction here: _awk uses blanks and newline-characters as default field separator. How blanks and newline characters are defined, depends on your locale, but genarally this includes spaces, tabs and the newline character._

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *blank string* means one or more spaces:

```
cut -f 1 -d ' ' "$filename"
```